# Incorrect output Project Euler #50

Tags: python, debugging, math

**Project  Euler problem 50 reads as follows:**

> The prime 41, can be written as the sum of six consecutive primes:
>
> 41 = 2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13
>   This is the longest sum of consecutive primes that adds to a prime below one-hundred.
>
> The longest sum of consecutive primes below one-thousand that adds to a prime, contains 21 terms, and is equal to 953.
>
> Which prime, below one-million, can be written as the sum of the most consecutive primes?

In my approach I pregenerate a list of primes using sieve of eratosthenes, then
in the function itself I keep adding succeeding elements of my prime number list
and each time i do that I check if the sum itself is prime and if it is I keep track of it as the biggest one and return it. Well that should work i guess ? Obviously the answer is incorrect, but the interesting thing is that when i change the sieve to generate primes below 100000 it doesn't give an index error but gives another result.

```
from algorithms import gen_primes

primes = [i for i in gen_primes(1000000)]


def main(n):
    idx, total, maximum = 0, 0, 0
    while total < n:
        total += primes[idx]
        idx += 1
        if total in primes:
            maximum = total
    return maximum


print(main(1000000))
```

Comment: Does your code yield 953 when capped to 1000?

Comment: Well ... is the problem with your computational loop, or with your list of primes?

Comment: It outputs 281, although it gives the correct result if capped at 100

Comment: @Prune I used the prime algorithm many times so I think that it is working correctly

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program doesn't solve the general problem: you *always* start your list of consecutive primes at the lowest, `2`.  Thus, what you return is the longest consecutive list starting at 2*, rather than *any* consecutive list of primes.

In short, you need another loop ...

```
start_idx = 0
while start_idx < len(primes) and best_len*primes[start_idx] < n:
    # find longest list starting at primes[start_idx]
    start_idx += 1
```

In case it's any help, the successful sequence begins between 1500 and 2000.